# Blazor WASM: List.Remove() call appears to be deleting all references to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I have an app that contains objects like so

```
Item
  - Guid Uid
  - String Title
  - Item Parent

Group : Item
  - List<Item> Items

Interface : Item

Field : Group
```

I am utilizing the HTML5 Drag and Drop API to allow the user to drag groups and interfaces to/from other groups.

In order to move, I add the Payload (dragged object) to the new object then remove it from it's Parent's Item List.

```cs
public void HandleOnDrop(){
    if(Payload.Uid != this.Uid){
        Console.WriteLine("Adding item " + Payload.Uid + " to " + this.Uid);
        Console.WriteLine("Removing item " + Payload.Uid + " from " + Payload.Parent.Uid);
        Items.Add(Payload);
        Payload.Parent.Items.Remove(Payload.Parent.Items.Find(x => x.Uid == Payload.Uid));
     }
     CssClass = "";
     Field.Refresh();
     Payload.Parent = this;
}
```

I have discovered that the Payload.Parent.Items.Remove() call causes the instance of the object to be disposed. If I comment it out, the drag functionality works fine except it doesn't remove the object from its original location. If I add an Interface element to several Groups, then delete that Interface, all references are removed as well as the original object is deleted.

I have even implemented IDisposable in the Item base class with a simple Console.WriteLine so I can see the objects being disposed. I would expect, since they were added to another List, that they would NOT be disposed. Why would they, if they are required by another object?

Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hello, have you attempted to reduce this problem to the most simple possible form, i.e. using a similar structure and reproducing the problem within a console app? It might be that this is simply how C# behaves and is unrelated to blazor. Alternatively, if you suspect that removing a single element from a list removes all elements and you suspect it is because of Blazor run-time (you should probably decide between client-side and server-side as well), could you reproduce the issue with simpler code (e.g. button click) and posting all of it without additinal clutter like css handling?

Comment: As additional note, could it be possible that assigning `Payload.Parent = this` could cause the original `Payload.Parent` to be no longer referenced and eligible for GC? Without all of your code, unfortunately, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I figured it out. Gotta use @key in the Components so they're tied to their objects. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use @key in Component Instantiation.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15846